# Unwrapping 360 video file

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-conversion

I'm looking for a way to unwrap surveillance camera 360 video file.
I tried this using ffmpeg :

```
ffmpeg -i Stationnement.mp4 -vf "v360=eac:e" Stationnement_Output.mp4
```

and got this error

> [libx264 @ 0000018192d30380] height not divisible by 2 (3840x3413)
> [vost#0:0/libx264 @ 0000018192d300c0] Error while opening encoder -
> maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height.

I also tried this using ffmpeg

```
 ffmpeg -i Stationnement.mp4 -vf "v360=equirect:output_width=3840:output_height=2160:output_format=rgb" Stationnement.mp4
```

And got this error

> Error applying option 'output_width' to filter 'v360': Option not
> found Option not found

I also try handbrake with sphere json preset and also failed the output video was still 360.

Anyone know something about it ?

Here's the media information :

> Général Nom complet                              :
> C:\Users\mysta\Downloads\Stationnement.mp4 Format
> : MPEG-4 Profil du format                         : Base Media
> Identifiant du codec                     : isom (isom/iso2/avc1/mp41)
> Taille du fichier                        : 53,8 Mio Durée
> : 34s 33 ms Débit global moyen                       : 13,3 Mb/s
> Images par seconde                       : 30,000 Im/s comment
> : Upscaled by Video2X encoder                                  :
> Lavf58.45.100
>
> Vidéo ID                                       : 1 Format
> : AVC Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
> Profil du format                         : High@L6 Paramètres du
> format                     : CABAC / 6 Ref Frames Paramètres du
> format, CABAC              : Oui Paramètres du format, RefFrames
> : 6 images Identifiant du codec                     : avc1 Identifiant
> du codec/Info                : Advanced Video Coding Durée
> : 34s 33 ms Débit                                    : 13,2 Mb/s
> Largeur                                  : 3 840 pixels Hauteur
> : 3 840 pixels Format à l'écran                         : 1,000 Type
> d'images/s                          : Variable Images par seconde
> : 30,000 Im/s Images/s mini                            : 29,412 Im/s
> Images/s maxi                            : 30,303 Im/s Espace de
> couleurs                       : YUV Sous-échantillonnage de la
> chrominance   : 4:2:0 Profondeur des couleurs                  : 8
> bits Type de balayage                         : Progressif
> Bits/(Pixel*Image)                       : 0.030 Taille du flux
> : 53,5 Mio (99%) Bibliothèque utilisée                    : x264 core
> 161 r3027 4121277 Paramètres d'encodage                    : cabac=1 /
> ref=6 / deblock=1:1:1 / analyse=0x3:0x113 / me=hex / subme=7 / psy=1 /
> psy_rd=0.40:0.00 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=1
> / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 /
> chroma_qp_offset=-2 / threads=18 / lookahead_threads=3 /
> sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0
> / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=5 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=1 / b_bias=0
> / direct=1 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=250 /
> keyint_min=25 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=40 /
> rc=crf / mbtree=1 / crf=17.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 /
> qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:0.60 mdhd_Duration
> : 34033 Codec configuration box                  : avcC
>
> Audio ID                                       : 2 Format
> : AAC LC Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio
> Codec Low Complexity Identifiant du codec                     :
> mp4a-40-2 Durée                                    : 34s 6 ms Type de
> débit                            : Constant Débit
> : 61,4 kb/s Canaux                                   : 1 canal Channel
> layout                           : M Echantillonnage
> : 48,0 kHz Images par seconde                       : 46,875 Im/s
> (1024 SPF) Mode de compression                      : Avec perte
> Taille du flux                           : 255 Kio (0%) Titre
> : Sound track Default                                  : Oui Alternate
> group                          : 1

Answer (score 0):

[v360 filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#v360) indeed doesn't have options called `output_width` or `output_height`. Not sure where you got that from.

You need to use a separate filter, either as secondary `vf` or within `filter_complex`. It's possible to achieve in many different ways, but `scale` one should be the easiest:

```
ffmpeg -i Stationnement.mp4 -vf "v360=eac:e,scale=3840:-2" Stationnement_Output.mp4
```

`-2` for `scale` means it should keep proportion, but make the height divisible by `2`.

Comment: The command worked thanks to you, the process happened flawlessly but the result is chaotic.

Comment: I don't know what "chaotic" means. You need to be way more specific than that and this is likely a different question to be posted.

Comment: @guillaumetremblay hello?